# How to create a list from list of list using scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections

I have following list:

```
List(List(vmnic4), List(vmnic5))
```

I want to change it to

```
List(vmnic4,vmnic5)
```

How Do I do it using scala??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flatten`:

```
List(List(vmnic4), List(vmnic5)).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in @Lee's answer, `flatten` is the way to go; a little more complicated approach that is condensed by `flatten` is `myList.flatMap(identity)`, namely `myList.map(identity).flatten`.